# Four items per on a carousel not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

When i am trying the below codeply in a local file i am not getting it properly, Please see the code pen [4 items per Carousel](https://www.codeply.com/go/YbRfxfTDN1). I have inserted the codeply in the question. Please see below

I just want to make 4 items per carousel , clicking on next , one item should be appended

Please see the below code, i need it to be horizontal not vertical

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    
    for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
         next = $(this).siblings(':first');
       }
        
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
});

})
```

```css
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-25%)
}
  
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left{ 
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container text-center my-3">
        <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
            <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=6">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4>Advances one slide at a time</h4>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below css and check

```
  .carousel-inner .img-fluid{
      float: left;
    }
```